# Macro that automatically updates URLs based on Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to automate editing links for a weekly report.

A report is run weekly which uses 6 different workbooks to provide a consolidated view. Each week the data is updated and hence the links need to be updated. I have recorded the below macro using the below macro tool but need it to be dynamic with references changing each week.

i.e. in the below I would like the Week number to change based on a cell reference in the consolidation sheet. So for the following week, week 2 would be come week 3 and week 3 would become week 4.

So for example in the current week. A1 = Week 3, A2  Week 4.

```
Sub Macro2()
    ChDir "X:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week 3"
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
        "X:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week 2\XXXXX Week 2.xlsx" _
        , NewName:= _
        "M:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week 3\XXXXX Week 3.xlsx" _
        , Type:=xlExcelLinks
End Sub
```

Then the following week I would update: A1: Week 4, and A2: Week 5.

```
Sub Macro2()

    ChDir "X:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week 5"
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
        "X:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week 4\XXXXX Week 4.xlsx" _
        , NewName:= _
        "M:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week 5\XXXXX Week 5.xlsx" _
        , Type:=xlExcelLinks
 End Sub
```

Comment: By *based on a cell reference in the consolidation sheet* what do you mean? Can you be more specific? Because the changing part is a simple `Replace(url, "Week X", "Week Y")`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I mean that I would like the code to change based on what is entered into a cell. So one week the code references to Week 4 and Week 5 based on what is in cell A1 (4) and A2 (5) for example. Then the following week I simply changes what is in cell A1 and A2 and the code updates. Thanks.

Comment: Hm maybe can you edit your question and add a part below with what the desired outcome would be for the following week based on whats in Cells A1 and A2?

Comment: Hi does that make sense better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an intial interpretation of what you're looking for.... might have misunderstood it so let me know

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim num1 As Long
    Dim num2 As Long
    Dim link1 As String
    Dim link2 As String

    ' enter your sheet name that has the A1 & A2 cells
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("enter your sheet name")
        num1 = .Range("A1").Value
        num2 = .Range("A2").Value
    End With

    ChDir "X:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week " & num2

    link1 = "X:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week X\XXXXX Week X.xlsx"
    link2 = "M:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\Week X\XXXXX Week X.xlsx"

    link1 = Replace(link1, "Week X", "Week " & num1)
    link2 = Replace(link2, "Week X", "Week " & num2)

    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=link1, NewName:=link2, Type:=xlExcelLinks


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi this is great and I think will do exactly what I need, thanks for your help. However I get the below error when trying to run it. Run time error 1004. Method 'ChangeLink' of object'_workbook' failed.

Comment: @ge123 have you tried with changing `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`? Is this macro in the workbook you are wanting to change links in?

Comment: I found out the error was in how I put the file paths in. Thank you for your help this does exactly what I needed .